# How to get 'milliseconds' as a part of time in perl?

Tags: perl

I need to get the time in the format `"20130808 12:12:12.123"` i.e., `"yyyymmdd hour:min:sec.msec"`.

I tried

```
my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime(time); 
$year += 1900;
$mon++;
if ($mon<10){$mon="0$mon"} 
if ($mday<10){$mday="0$mday"} 
if ($hour<10){$hour="0$hour"} 
if ($min<10){$min="0$min"} 
if ($sec<10){$sec="0$sec"}  but this doesn't provide the `msec` as a part of time.
```

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 36):

Here's a complete script. As proposed before, it is using `Time::HiRes::time` for microsecond support, and it's also using `POSIX::strftime` for easier formatting. Unfortunately `strftime` cannot deal with microseconds, so this has to be added manually.

```
use Time::HiRes qw(time);
use POSIX qw(strftime);

my $t = time;
my $date = strftime "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S", localtime $t;
$date .= sprintf ".%03d", ($t-int($t))*1000; # without rounding

print $date, "\n";
```

If you don't mind to use a CPAN module, then I would propose the excellent Time::Moment module:

```
use Time::Moment;
print Time::Moment->now->strftime("%Y%m%d %T%3f"), "\n";
```

And if it may be formatted as an ISO8601 date including a time zone offset and microseconds instead of milliseconds, then it's simply:

```
print Time::Moment->now->to_string, "\n";
```

Comment: This worked for me..No need to install any package...Thanks

Comment: One can also use this similar but slightly different solution:

`use Time::HiRes qw( gettimeofday );`
`use POSIX qw( strftime );`
`my ($sec, $usec) = gettimeofday();`
`printf( "%s.%03d", strftime( "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S", localtime $sec ), $usec/1000 );`

Comment: I don't get any syntax errors, but the milliseconds are always coming out to '000' for me, on Perl 5.30.0/Ubuntu 20.

Comment: @k-den This is strange --- I can test on the exactly same perl/OS combination (system perl on Ubuntu 20.04), and it still works as expected. Just an idea: maybe you're on top of a virtualization which is doing strange things with the clock? What about other utilities capable of returning sub-second times, e.g `date +%F%T.%N`?

Comment: `date` looks good.  `$ date +%F%T.%N` 
`2021-04-1413:41:03.099557465`

Comment: @k-den Maybe you omitted the "time" import? In this case you would get the CORE integer-returning time() function, which would show this effect.

Comment: @SlavenRezic Yep. I don't get why Perl coders always insist on using unqualified function names. What I mean is, why not just call `Time::HiRes::time()` and thereby eliminate any ambiguity?

Answer (score 12):

use [Time::HiRes](http://search.cpan.org/~zefram/Time-HiRes-1.9725/HiRes.pm)

Looking at this briefly, it can provide milliseconds since epoch fairly
easily but didn't seem to extend localtime(), so there's probably a bit of work
involved in using it in a full calendar context.

Here's a working example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Format qw/%time/;
use Time::HiRes qw/gettimeofday/;

my $time = gettimeofday; # Returns ssssssssss.uuuuuu in scalar context

print qq|$time{'yyyymmdd hh:mm:ss.mmm', $time}\n|;
```

Comment: [Time::HiRes](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/HiRes.html) is a core module which means that it's a part of the distribution.

Comment: `my $time = join '.', gettimeofday;` is prone to error, because in list context, milliseconds are returned WITHOUT leading zeros (e.g. when time is 1234567890.000123, you are concatenating 1234567890.123, which is wrong. You only need `$time = gettimeofday`, which in scalar context already returns '1234567890.000123'.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the code that @JackieJames added to my answer.  I wish Stack Overflow's software indicated attribution correctly without having to search through the edits.